# Windows Task Scheduler in MVC PHP application

Tags: php, windows, cakephp, scheduled-tasks

I need to run a daily call to a controller action in my MVC application (CakePHP framework) and I know Windows Server can run a PHP script as a daily task in the Scheduled Task Manager. How would I call the method in the Controller if I can call it as `www.test.com/reports/import` -this imports from a .csv to a MYSQL table. Or in the script how would I tell it to follow CakePHP's MVC "workflow", call controller and call model method.

Comment: Why not using shells and CLI if you are running a script via shell/cronjob etc? way cleaner than trying to invoke some controllers.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: You can read about it in the manual here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html IMO the biggest advantage is that you don't have to expose a public 'url' to tasks that should not be public. E.g. imagine if someone 'discovered' that URL and keeps hammering the same URL many times, then you've got yourself a possible DOS attack ;)

Comment: Answer the post so i can give you credit.